# Strange string appended to typeName in DataContractResolver.ResolveName for generic type

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have implemented a custom DataContractResolver for my WCF service, which takes a known list of types and looks them up by name. In most cases it works (including for generic arrays, e.g. "ArrayOfMyClass"). However, for other generic types a seemingly random eight-character string is appended to the end of the `typeName` parameter in [`ResolveName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractresolver.resolvename(v=vs.110).aspx). In this example the string is `AevzrKY9`:

> Error in line 1 position 345. Element `'http://services.contoso.com/QueryService:QueryResult'` contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Contoso.Services.Contract.Infrastructure:PagedListResultsOfPersonSearchResultAevzrKY9'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider changing the implementation of the ResolveName method on your DataContractResolver to return a non-null value for name 'PagedListResultsOfPersonSearchResultAevzrKY9' and namespace `'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Contoso.Services.Contract.Infrastructure'`.

I have also encountered the string `MZHTWXIT`.

My hacky workaround is to first check if the type is registered and if not, check again without the final eight characters. This seems pretty unreliable and I'd like to have a more foolproof way to deal with this odd appendage.

The actual question: **What is this string which is appended to the typeName and how can I stop it from being appended (or deal with it some other way)?**

---

Full source for the DataContractResolver is below:

```
public sealed class KnownTypesDataContractResolver : DataContractResolver
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Type> _knownTypes;

    public KnownTypesDataContractResolver(IEnumerable<Type> types)
    {
        _knownTypes = (
            from type in types.Distinct()
            group type by type.FullName into g
            select g.First())
            .ToDictionary(GetName);
    }

    public override Type ResolveName(string typeName, string typeNamespace, Type declaredType,
        DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver)
    {
        // I have no idea why this string gets appended to PagedListResult generic typename but removing it seems to work...
        var genericTypeName = typeName.Contains("MZHTWXIT");
        var knownTypeName = genericTypeName ? typeName.Substring(0, typeName.IndexOf("MZHTWXIT")) : typeName;

        Type type;

        if (_knownTypes.TryGetValue(knownTypeName, out type))
            return type;

        if (knownTypeName.StartsWith("ArrayOf"))
        {
            if (_knownTypes.TryGetValue("ListOf" + knownTypeName.Substring(7), out type))
                return type;
        }

        var withoutFinalEightChars = typeName.Substring(0, typeName.Length - 8);
        if (_knownTypes.TryGetValue(withoutFinalEightChars, out type))
            return type;

        return knownTypeResolver.ResolveName(typeName, typeNamespace, declaredType, null);
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public override bool TryResolveType(Type type, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver,
        out XmlDictionaryString typeName, out XmlDictionaryString typeNamespace)
    {
        if (!knownTypeResolver.TryResolveType(type, declaredType, null, out typeName, out typeNamespace))
        {
            typeName = new XmlDictionaryString(XmlDictionary.Empty, type.Name, 0);
            typeNamespace = new XmlDictionaryString(XmlDictionary.Empty, type.Namespace, 0);
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static string GetName(Type type)
    {
        return type.IsArray
            ? "ArrayOf" + GetName(type.GetElementType())
            : type.IsGenericType ? GetGenericName(type) : type.Name;
    }

    private static string GetGenericName(Type type)
    {
        var typeDef = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        var name = typeDef.Name.Substring(0, typeDef.Name.IndexOf('`'));
        return name + "Of" + string.Join(string.Empty, type.GetGenericArguments().Select(GetName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked out the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616185, which also talks about generic `PagedList`s where the exact type name ends with a seemingly random suffix?

Comment: @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam - good find! I'll check it out, thanks

Comment: Another one is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172265

Comment: @StephenReindl perfect! That's almost an exact duplicate of this question. I can't close this one until the bounty is up otherwise I would. If you want to write an answer on the above (the question you linked is 8 years old) I'll gladly give you the bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [How can I control the name of generic WCF return types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172265) you can define your return type name using the [DataContract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute using the `Name` property like this:

```
[DataContract(Name = "ResponseOf{0}")]
public class Response<T>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it forces you to decorate simple classes with WCF specific attributes. How could we achieve this without attributes?

Comment: One option would be to use a shared library (used by client and server) containing all generic response types. Use this library in the service dialog. In this case the names should be the same for server and client.